# How to mark a post as Question on Yammer?

Tags: yammer

As I have read on Yammer website and other sources, Yammer is having a Questions application where we can mark a post as question and other members can answer that. But I could not find a option to mark a post as question. If anybody has done that please let me know.

For reference -

https://www.yammer.com/about/applications

https://www.yammer.com/apps/questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions are special posts in Yammer. You cannot turn a regular post into a question but you can create a new question either by:

- Looking for the “more” link under your Company section in the sidebar. Questions are somewhere down the list of application links.
- Or select **Question** from the *Share a...* menu on the website.

Note that this is valid for the main Yammer website.

Yammer clients need to handle questions in their own way to allow you to post a question instead of a regular post.

Comment: Thanks Laurent. Actually at the time of asking this there was no option for "Quesion" in 'Share a..' menu but today its visible. I don't know if this is anyhow related to asking the question here on stack exchange :)